# How to list all services in an android device

Tags: android, android-service

I am looking for a **reliable** way to programmatically find and list **all** available services in an Android device (both running and not running).

The closest thing I could find in the API is [getRunningServices()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRunningServices%28int%29) on `ActivityManager` but even that is marked boldly:

**Note: this method is only intended for debugging or implementing service management type user interfaces.**

and it lists only **running** services anyway.

Is there a reliable way to find all available services in a given Android device?

(ideally, if such method exist, should be compatible with API/SDK 8 and up)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can [enumerate all packages](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getInstalledPackages%28int%29) and [retrieve their services](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInfo.html#services):

```
List<PackageInfo> pkgs = getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_SERVICES);
for(PackageInfo pkg : pkgs) {
  // You can now use pkg.services
}
```

Compatible to API 1.

Answer (score 1):

In the past I have used the following:

List list = activityManager.getRunningServices(maxNum);

I have created an example [here](https://www.panayiotisgeorgiou.net/list-running-services-on-android-device/)