# How can i find list all services in an android device

Tags: android, android-service

I am looking for a reliable way to programmatically find and list all available services in an Android device (both running and not running).

The closest thing I could find in the API is [getRunningServices()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRunningServices%28int%29) on ActivityManager but even that is marked boldly:

**Note: this method is only intended for debugging or implementing service management type user interfaces.**

and it lists only running services anyway.

(ideally, if such method exist, should be compatible with API/SDK 15 and up)

Comment: you may use this answer  http://stackoverflow.com/q/19758611/5090932

Comment: I saw this link to create questions. The problem is that the list does not show all apps !!!

Comment: A application such as Security 360 can not be displayed on the list !!!

Comment: If Security 360 is not in the list, then it doesn't have a `Service` component. That application is probably a "Device Manager" anyway.